# HTTP get results in IOException

Tags: java, http, google-calendar-api

I've been given 'q' value in the list event api url, since I need to filter out events have same word. I have given this url in POSTMAN and it works fine

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?q=test&maxResults=2500
```

But when I give the same url in java using HTTP URL Connection, I get an empty list

```
URL host=new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?q=test&maxResults=2500");
HttpURLConnection hosturl=(HttpURLConnection) host.openConnection();
hosturl.setRequestMethod("GET");
hosturl.setConnectTimeout(15000);
hosturl.setReadTimeout(15000);
hosturl.setDoInput(true);
hosturl.setDoOutput(true);
hosturl.setRequestProperty("authorization","Bearer ya18.GlycBTDFFefffnj4U77Zua2iSxd7dUNgF2UEdeIkNf6b3A5jsXRwgCS5iwLp-Vi4k49xWWtjm78YnNz5ghatN4GH97gokE222ddwewDDFS_Ga3wcHw");
hosturl.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
int responseCode=hosturl.getResponseCode();
```

I got IOException in last line of the above code.
Please help me with this! Thank you!

Comment: Tip: use primary  instead of abcdefrgre@gmail.com it will be the primary calendar of the current authenticated user.   Please edit your question and include an example of the code thats not working.  this isnt enough to test I am not seeing how you are applying the authentication.

Comment: try testing it here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.list?calendarId=primary&q=test&_h=2&

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for your suggestions. I've tried in the apis-explorer, it is working fine in that, if i give the same url in java code, i get the error

Comment: Any special reason why your not using the client library for this?  why reinvent the wheel?  please edit and include the full exception.

Comment: I'm building an application and I usually use this for all my apis, I need to learn and test client library before using it. Is there something like this parameter(q) will work only in client library?

Comment: No what you are doing should work, my java skills arent up to helping you debug it though it looks fine to me which means its probably a java issue.   I have edited your question to see if you can get some more attention.

Comment: Thanks alot @DaImTo Even when I give encode the string for q value, it doesn't work

Comment: is there more detailed description available with the IOException that gets thrown? That's quite generic and could cover a number of root causes. Could just be a connection / firewall issue, for instance, rather than a problem with the structure of your HTTP request. If it was reaching google but google was returning an error response I'd expect a different kind of error.

Comment: Google returns backend error when i try it through JAVA. And same happens when i try it in POSTMAN and encodes the q value. @ADyson

Comment: What kind of backend error? If it works in the API explorer, as you stated earlier, but not in other tools then I would suggest it means you're constructing the request incorrectly, or not providing credentials or something. If you use your browser tools you can see what request the API explorer sends and try to imitate it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to pass those urlparameters (q=test&maxResults=2500) in HttpURLConnection GET Request @ADyson

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the way you're doing it now. How about answering my questions from my last comment instead.

Comment: @ADyson I donno the kind of backend error, it just returns a json of Global Backend error, with error code 503. I've been constructing my url parameters in url itself, it works for other parameters except 'q'.

Comment: A 503 is a HTTP status code (which you could google) meaning "Service Unavailable"